# What is required in C++ to compile -std=c++0x?

Tags: c++, command-line, compiler-errors, terminal

I downloaded my program from my schools server to work on it offline. I have GNU installed but when I try to compile it on my Mac using my makefile and I get this error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
```

I'm assuming I'm missing a plugin or something on my Mac?

Thanks

Comment: @Jerry: I wouldn't call `clang` *wrong* -- it has the best C++11 support around.  But it is different, and won't work with the same options.

Comment: What? I use GNU compiler.

Comment: Ok, then what version of GCC did you install?  `clang` is a very good choice for C++11 programming.  The support is better, and the error messages are easier to understand.

Comment: Please cut+paste the output of `g++ --version`. That'll help.

Comment: I'm assuming the most current? Lol I think it's updated with Xcode updates? Sorry I don't know much when it comes to compilers. My professor and all my CS classes have just used GNU so I'm even less familiar with anything else unfortunately.

Comment: @JGeis: I definitely wouldn't expect Xcode to update your GCC install.  It's designed to work with `clang`.

Answer (score 0):

`-std=c++0x` is the option for G++.  `clang` is the Mac compiler, and it looks like no flag is needed.

Actually, `clang` does support the same `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. So what do I need to fix it?

Comment: Set the $CXX variable in your makefile to `clang++`, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man pages for whatever version of gcc you have installed to confirm it supports the argument in question.

Edit: Just to clarify because no one has spelled it out yet. c++0x refers to features that are part of the new standard, the 'state of the art' so to speak.  From the gcc man pages:

> c++0x The working draft of the upcoming ISO C ++ 0x standard. This option enables experimental features that are likely to be included in C ++ 0x. The working draft is constantly changing, and any feature that is enabled by this flag may be removed from future versions of GCC if it is not part of the C ++ 0x standard.

Comment: Alright it says 4.2, but 4.8 is the current stable version?

Comment: @JGeis Get a new version of gcc.  If you want to use the 2011 standard, you'll need a compiler from after 2007.